# Can I switch Ubuntu Pro machine registration?

Tags: ubuntu-advantage

I have a server that I would like to hand over to somebody else. It's currently attached to the Ubuntu Pro free tier, registered to my Ubuntu One account so I'd like that to be on their ID.

What's the easiest way of doing that? Should I run `pro detach` then attach using their ID? Will that preserve the settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran `sudo pro detach` which disabled the various services associated with the subscription (it requires a reboot to actually remove them, but I ignored that).

I then ran `sudo pro attach [tokenID]` which appeared to read the configuration in `/etc/ubuntu-advantage/uaclient.conf` (proxy settings, etc.)

Running `pro status` shows the new account working fine. I can now hand over the machine to the new owner.